# problems with Azure LogicApps Workflows

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, workflowservice

since today I have problems to create new workflows in LogicApps.

I can open the resources, but I get the following error message:

"GetCallFailed. Failed fetching operations."

I changed anything. It ws from one point to another. Even if I want to create new workflows Built-In is not working only Azure.

Here is a Screeshot:

[image: Azure Logic App Problems]

Maybe you experienced something similar and an help me.

Best regards

Matthias

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: Hello! no I restarted the Workflow Resource. Now it's working again.

Comment: @Matthias Convert it to answer as it will be helpful for other community members.

Answer (score 0):

this problem was solved easily. If you have the error message that your logic app runs out of space or a similiar message or that you can't load some azure content, then you can click on logic apps main page und click on "restart" then the problem is solved quickly.

[Restart LogicApps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imo2X.png)

Best regards

Matthias